# Solutions that oscillate more rapidly

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions, derivatives

Which one of the following two equations has solutions that oscillate more rapidly?

$$x''+\sqrt{t^6+3t^5+1} x =0$$

$$ x''+2t^3 x =0$$

I was trying to use sturm separation theorem but not getting exact approach towards it!!

Is there any direct way to do it?

*Edit:* The book from where I have given this question has answer as first equation in the hints provided at the back of book.
Book name: "A Textbook  on Ordinary  Differential  Equations" by Shair Ahmad, Antonio Ambrosetti(Second Edition)-Chapter5-Exercise-D2

Comment: Why not solve the two?

Comment: @Tavish: because it is not very practical. The second DE can be solved by Bessel functions, the first one is even more intricate.

Comment: I solved both numerically and the second oscillates much more than the first one

Comment: Where is the difficulty in applying the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem for $t>2$?

Comment: @Lutz for t>2 second function I say $q(t)=2t^3$ becomes greater than first function $p(t)=\sqrt{t^6+3t^5+1}$ but if I suppose that some solution of first ode has consecutive zeros then we get solution of second ode at some point between the consecutive points to be zero but the solution of second ode must satisfy condition like y(a)=0 where a is zero of solution of first ode. To apply sturm comparison theorem this condition is needed. How to get this condition?

Comment: No, there is no condition on having simultaneous roots. It may help in some situations to assume such, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @Lutz I don't know why the answer is first equation in book...

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that $t$ is confined in an interval with small amplitude we may assume that $t^3$ is approximately constant. By recalling that a solution of $x''+ K x=0$ (with $K>0$) has a frequency of $\frac{\sqrt{K}}{2\pi}$ we immediately get that a solution of $x''(t)+2t^3 x(t)=0$ oscillates faster than a solution of $x''(t)+\sqrt{t^6+3t^5+1}\,x(t)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem. To refine that, consider $u(t)=x_2(ct)$ for the solution $x_2$ of the second equation. Then
$$
u''(t)=c^2x_2''(ct)=-2c^5t^3x_2(ct)=-2c^5t^3u(t).
$$
Now if we set $2c^5=1$, then $t^3$ will always be smaller than $\sqrt{t^6+3t^5+1}$, so that $x_2(t/\sqrt[5]2)$ has less roots than the solution $x_1$ of the first equation.

On the other hand, for any $c>1/\sqrt[5]2$ there is some $t_c$ so that for $t>t_c$ one also has $4c^{10}t^6>t^6+3t^5+1$, so that on $[t_c,\infty)$ the scaled function $x_2(ct)$ has more roots than the unscaled $x_1(t)$. As $c<1$ can be chosen, this implies that the root density of the unscaled $x_2$ is even greater.

Asymptotically, as a rule of thumb, whenever $x_1$ has $7$ roots on some interval, $x_2$ will have at least $8$, as $7/8>1/\sqrt[5]2$.

Answer (score -1):

Just solve them and plot the two:

[image]

The full forms have constants, that must be set for initial conditions.  For example $c_1 \cos t + c_2 \sin t$.  In the above, I've set all constants to $1$, just to reveal the periods... the focus of the question.

Comment: The first one is wrong. If we plug in the DE we get $\left(\sqrt{t^6+3 t^5+1}-1\right) (\sin t+\cos t)$ and not zero